# Android - Stack CardView without third party libraries?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

Given that we can create a [CardView without external libraries](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/cardview), can we also stack said cards without an external library?

I've searched the web for solutions, but the <s>best</s> easiest I've found is implementing stacked cards using [SwipeDeck2](https://github.com/aaronbond/SwipeDeck2). I haven't seen anything that uses the stock CardView. What does [Google Primer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.primer&hl=en) use then?

Comment: "Given that we can create a CardView without external libraries" -- from my standpoint, that uses an external library: `com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0`. "can we also stack said cards without an external library?" -- what is your definition of "stack" here, and what is your definition of "external library"?

Comment: I second that @CommonsWare